# How do I get a value from a url and use as a variable in an apple script?

Tags: php, bash, applescript

I found how to pause and resume SABnzbd using the API
`http://localhost:8080/sabnzbd/api?mode=pause`
but how do I get the true or false value from here http://www.flatmat.net/intr-over.php (this is a PHP script that I wrote) to use in an applescript(or bash script) to pause SABnzb if true or resume if false?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is easy in Bash using `curl`, which should be available on OS X by default:

```
value=$( curl "http://www.flatmat.net/intr-over.php" -o "-" 2>&1 | tr -d "\r\n" )
```

The `tr` command eliminates unnecessary newlines from the HTTP response. You could use it like this:

```
if [ "$value" = false ]
then
    # resume
else
    # pause
fi
```

Note that this will pause on unknown responses from the PHP script as well.

Comment: Thanks Michael. I was able to use this in my applescript fine with one change - just removing the quotes around the var `$value`. Thanks for your help